# Django Haystack search in Html

Tags: html, django, search, elasticsearch, django-haystack

i was just wondering (since i didn't find anything quick on Google) if its possible (and how do i achieve that) to search directly in an html file, and ignore the tags or not as i please?

explaining a bit further. we wrote a crawler and obviously the crawler gives back the HTML of the page. But if i feel like searching the content of the crawler, do i need 2 separate fields one with html and one without or i can just have one field with html and search ignoring the html tags or not.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i correctly understand you, all you need is to set search indexes without html tags?

We solved that problem this way:

```
class PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(model_attr='text', use_template=True, document=True)
```

and in template (`search/indexes/blogs/post_test.html`) we just used `striptags` filter

```
{{ object.content|striptags }}
```

After that you need to `build_schema` and `rebuild_index`. Now it search correctly without tags.

Comment: ill try this approach and let you know if it worked :) thanks